# Kongregate "Add to Favorites" button callback

Tags: javascript, api, kongregate

Just checking to see if anyone uses kongregate. If so, I am having an issue.

There is no information on how to handle or response to “Add to Favorites” button.
Are there any callbacks or notifications that may help to do this?

Thanks.